# jQuery hide/show with select tag

Tags: jquery, html, css

I've been asked to create a hide/show function with a select tag. The function pretty much would be when you click on one of the options in the select tag it will open a div associate with the div of course. To be honest I have no idea how approach this function. Find below the html code.

```
<div class="adwizard">
                            <select id="selectdrop" name="selectdrop" class="adwizard-bullet">
                                    <option value="adwizard">AdWizard</option>
                                    <option value="collateral">Collateral Ordering Tool</option>
                                    <option value="ebrochure">eBrochures</option>
                                    <option value="brand">Brand Center</option>
                                    <option value="funtees">FunTees</option>
                            </select>
                    </div>

                     <div class="panels">   
                        <div id="adwizard" class="sub-box showhide">
                            <img src="../images/bookccl/img-adwizard.gif" width="95" height="24" alt="AdWizard" />
                            <p>Let Carnival help you grow your business with our great tools! Lor ipsum dolor sit amet. <a href="https://www.carnivaladwizard.com/home.asp">Learn More</a></p>
                        </div>

                         <div id="collateral" class="sub-box showhide">
                            <p>The Collateral Ordering Tool makes it easy for you to order destination brochures and the sales DVD for that upcoming event. <a href="http://carnival.litorders.com/workplace.asp">Learn More</a></p>
                        </div>

                        <div id="ebrochure" class="sub-box showhide">
                            <img src="../images/bookccl/img-ebrochure.gif" width="164" height="39" alt="Brochures" />
                            <p>Show your clients that you're listening to their specific vacation needs by delivering relevant planning info quickly.  <a href="http://productiontrade.carnivalbrochures.com/start.aspx">Learn More</a></p>
                        </div>

                         <div id="brand" class="sub-box showhide">
                            <p>Carnival Brand Center is where you'll find information on our strategy, guidlines, templates and artwork.   <a href="https://carnival.monigle2.net/user_info.asp?login_type=agent">Learn More</a></p>
                        </div>

                        <div id="funtees" class="sub-box showhide">
                            <img src="../images/bookccl/img-funtees.gif" width="164" height="39" alt="Funtees" />
                            <p>Create your very own Fun Design shirts to commemorate that special occasion aboard a Carnival "Fun Ship!"  <a href="http://carnival.victorydyo.com/">Learn More</a></p>
                        </div>
                    </div><!-- ends .panel -->
                    <a class="view" href="#">See All Marketing Tools</a>
                </div>
```

Comment: note that you should accept the best answer that helped you by clicking the gray checkmark on the left side of that answer and vote for good answers by clicking the up-arrow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I took your code above and [made a jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fbcS9/3/) with (I believe) the functionality you were looking for.

Comment: It was close but not the effect I'm looking for. I need one of the options to be opened and the others to be closed until they are clicked,

Comment: Yea, I realized I missed the hide after I first saved it. Thanks for fixing :) Updated to your link in the answer.

Comment: @Gaby thank you so much I'd in debt to you all my life it works beautifully.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#selectdrop').change(function() {
        $('.panels div').hide();
        var panel = $(this).val();
        $('#' + panel).show();
    });
});
```

Untested, but I think that'll work ... it's very rough, but a jumping off point, and can most definitely be done better.

Answer (score 0):

Or better

```
<head>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.panels div').hide();// << IMPORTANT
    $('#selectdrop').change(function() {
        $('.panels div').slideUp();
        var panel = $(this).val();
        $('#' + panel).slideDown();
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
.. The page ..
</body>
```

Comment: The problem with this one is that I need to have one of the divs selected. But works perfect.